# OnScrolling new page is automatically loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

Actually i have seen a website, where while scrolling the new page is automatically loaded and it is appended to the old page.

Not only the page, URL also getting changed while scrolling.

Completely I don't know how to implement this. This is the website which I have seen **[matt](http://ma.tt/)**. Here just scroll down, there will be a *infinite scrollbar* concept, and also URL address bar will change automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to append dynamic contents to the existed page from some database on scroll then make a ajax call on scroll and also rate limit the number of calls by using throttle function which will return you a throttled version of ajax call that is your ajax call will only be served atmost once during the wait millisecond time period.

```
var myajax = _.throttle(/*your ajax call goes here*/, wait/*time in ms*/);
```

**_.throttle()** is part of *underscore.js* library and if you don't want to include this library, then you can use my version of throttle that is,

```
function myThrottle(func, wait, leading) {
  var lastCall = 0, timeout = null,

  execute = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
    func();
  };

  return function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (leading && (lastCall == 0 || (currentTime - lastCall) > wait)) {
      lastCall = currentTime;
      func();
    }

    else if (!leading && !timeout)
      timeout = setTimeout(execute, wait);
  };
}
```

here the third argument **leading** if **true** than call will be made on leading edge of wait duration blocking further calls otherwise on trailing edge(default behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var documentBottom = $(document).height(), // cache document height
    page = 0; // current page number

$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    // if window scroll position bigger than document bottom minus 300px,
    // then make ajax request and append result to container
    if($(window).scrollTop() > documentBottom - 300) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: { page: page },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.my-container').append(data); // appending result

                // cache new document height
                documentBottom = $(document).height();

                page += 1; // change page number

                //change url in address bar
                window.history.pushState({},"","/page/"+page); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```